# isomorphic relation between groups with semidirect product

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group such that $G= H \rtimes‎ K$ and let $A$ be a subgroup of $G$ and $A  ‎‎\cong‎ K$. Then can we say that $G  ‎‎\cong‎ H \rtimes‎ A$?
Note. $G= H \rtimes‎ K$, ie $G=HK$, $H \cap K=1$, $H$ is normal in $G$. Also $K$ acts on $H$ by conjugation.

Comment: Do you mean the external semidirect product $H \rtimes A$, with its action on $H$ equivalent to the action of $K$ on $H$? That's obviously isomorphic to $G$. Perhaps you mean, instead, the internal product $HA$? (where $H$ represents the embedding of the factor $H$ into $G$).

Comment: please see question again

Comment: The edit doesn't help much. You've written $H \rtimes A$, but that doesn't tell me how you define that semidirect product. In particular, what action of $A$ on $H$ do you have in mind? Is it the same as (equivalent to) the action of $K$ on $H$ in the semidirect product $H \rtimes K$?

Comment: if you dont know group theory, then dont answer it PLEAse!!! my question is obvious!!!

Comment: Oh, $K$ is normal in $G$. So I should ask, rather, what is the action of $H$ on $A$ in your semidirect product $H \rtimes A$? Is it equivalent to its action on $K$ in $H \rtimes K$?

Comment: this action is defined action in semidirect product, conjugation!

Comment: Then no, it is not necessary that $H \rtimes A \cong G$. You have only mentioned that $A \cong K$, and $K \unlhd G$, so there are no other restrictions. I can (in an imaginary example) choose $A$ to be *any* subgroup of $G$ satisfying that condition. Firstly, $A$ might not be normal in $G$! Secondly, since I'm also free to define $G$ as anything I wish (by defining $H$ and $K$), I can choose $H \cong K$, and $A = H$ (identically equal to the subgroup $H$). Then $H \rtimes H = H$. So unless you add some conditions, anything is possible.

Comment: Ok thanks for response

Comment: If $G = H \rtimes K$, it should be $H$ who is normal in $G$ (the symbol $\rtimes$ looks a lot like $\lhd$ and should be "pointing at" the subgroup that's normal in $G$).

Comment: sorry, my means is $H$ is normal, it was mistake in typing!!

Comment: Mr  M. Vinay, sorry $H$ is normal, can you answer?

Comment: One problem with this question is that $H \rtimes K$ does not define the group semidirect product unambiguously. You also need an action $\phi:K \to {\rm Aut}(H)$ of $K$ on $H$.

Comment: this is equivalent, exist of semidirect product and exist of this homomorphism!

Comment: @DerekHolt (I know your group theory understanding far exceeds mine!) Is this ambiguity fixed if the question were phrased as "Let $G$ be a group with subgroups $H, K$ such that $HK = G,\ H \cap K = 1$ and $H \lhd G$, so that we write $G = H \rtimes K$ as an (internal) semidrect product. Suppose further that there exists a subgroup $A$ of $G$ with $A \cong K$. Is it true that $G$ is an (internal) semidirect product $G = H \rtimes A$ as well (i.e., that $HA = G$ and $H \cap A = 1$)?"

Comment: @pjs36 Ah, *that* is the proper condition which makes the question non-trivial. But still the answer is no (maybe surprisingly, unless you're familiar with the wiles of group theory)!

Comment: @ pjs36. yes it is

Comment: @pjs36 The way the question is phrased currently, we could have $H \cong K$ and $A=H$.

Comment: @user330247 The point I am making is that your current question "Is $G \cong H \rtimes A$" does not make sense because $H \rtimes A$ does not necessarily uniquely define a group up to isomorphism. If you are asking "Is $G \cong H \rtimes A$ for some semidirect product $H \rtimes A$" then the answer is obviously yes when $K \cong A$.